# Как дать разрешение терминалу на работу с мышью OS X Ventura 13.0.1?

Tags: python, mac, pyautogui

Всем привет, не работает pyautogui модуль на OS X. Пользуюсь методом "pyautogui.moveTo()"
Ошибку не выдает, однако изменений никаких не происходит. Пробовал менять координаты в методе - все тщетно. На английской версии прочитал что проблема исходит от того, что якобы у терминала нет доступа к мыши, проверил директорию доступ к диску - дал доступ всему, что там было. Не дало никаких результатов.
Прошу о помощи, уже не первый модуль, который отказывается работать. До этого были проблемы с pynput. Так и не решились.

Comment: а вон тот способ вам не помог ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58066712/how-to-get-pyautoguis-click-working-on-mac

Comment: Я уже решил вопрос, попробовал запустить не через шарм а через IDLE стандартный, он заново запросил разрешения и я их выдал. В общем, в универсальном доступе на самом деле нужно давать разрешения. После этого все модули заработали)

Answer (score 0):

Я уже решил вопрос, попробовал запустить не через шарм а через IDLE стандартный, он заново запросил разрешения и я их выдал.
В общем, в универсальном доступе на самом деле нужно давать разрешения я долго к этому шел. После этого все модули заработали) Так что если у кого то будет такая же проблема проверяйте там)